# Regular Expression to match word repeated twice (i.e. hello hello hello)

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I have a java regular expression given by my CS2 instructor that checks if a word is repeated:

```
\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b
```

How can I modify this to check if a word is repeated **twice** as in "hello hello hello" or "hello world hello hello"

If possible, I'd just like to be pointed in the right direction, not an outright solution (after all, I need to learn this). I think my problem is that I don't understand word boundaries well.

Comment: What does `\1` match?

Comment: (I wanted OP, but ok.) Can you re-use it?

Comment: @Cupcake Let the OP answer.

Comment: I believe that it matches the first defined group, which would be... '(\\w+)' ? That part confuses me, since it is inside the word boundary.

Comment: Also, [this](http://regex101.com/) is a great regex tool.

Comment: @nathanoday There really isn't a concept of "inside" or "outside" word boundaries.  I believe `\b` just means "Match if this position is between a word character and a non-word character, or between a word character and the beginning or end of the string".  It doesn't cause the matcher to break the source up into words, or look at the source with any kind of "structure", or anything.  This is difficult to explain, but the bottom line is that I think you're worrying about things you don't need to worry about.

Comment: @ajb The Oracle tutorials say _"You can make your pattern matches more precise by specifying such information with boundary matchers. For example, maybe you're interested in finding a particular word, but only if it appears at the beginning or end of a line."_

Since I don't care where in the string I find the duplicate words, does that mean I should forget about word boundaries?

Comment: @nathanoday Right--this quote doesn't mention anything about "inside" or "outside".  You use `\\b` so that you don't match `"hellox"` in your string.  You can use it wherever you want.  You don't have to use them in pairs.  You can use a regex like `"\\bcat"` to match any word beginning with `cat`, but it can be `cat` or `catalog` or `catastrophe` or whatever.  You don't need a `\\b` to match the end of the word, if you don't want one.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. It doesn't segment the string into words, it just makes sure that you get that word and not a substring of that word. That is actually what I want, but isn't the main problem at this point. So, why does `\\b(\\w+)` have a `\\b` ? Is it just defining that as a word in case it is referenced later? (maybe group 1, `\\1` )

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No kidding, that is a really good tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you seem to want to learn this yourself I'll give you a helpful [Oracle Link.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)  And secondly I'll suggest you pay attention to what exactly you're trying to achieve, a pattern with **three** of the same **word**. Hope that helps and isn't too obvious.  Comment if you need more help.

Edit: Sorry I forgot the second link [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)  This page is also helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Now, from my limited understanding, I know that `X{n}` will match expression X, n times. How do I take X to be an entire word? I imagine it has to do with reading word characters `\w` perhaps, until I reach a whitespace? And then grouping it. Hmm... this is where I'm fuzzy.

Comment: Yes, the example you've given the \w is the part that has to do with the first word it finds.  You shouldn't need the X{n} stuff.

Comment: Oh, I thought I was going to check for that word `n` times though? Or is that what the grouping reference `\\1` is for?

Comment: Yes, that's what the \\1 is for, so I'd suggest thinking about what the expression means between the \\b and the other \\b, because in a simplified manor that's just describing a group of text in some form or fashion.

You have 3 main parts, the \\w+, the \\s+, and the \\1.  You're on the right track though.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to figure out the anatomy of the expression that you are given. It describes a string that *captures* a non-empty sequence of word characters `(\\w+)` that begins at a word boundary, which is followed by a non-empty sequence of spaces `\\s+`, followed by the content of the captured group, which is *not* part of a longer word (that is what the `\\b` does at the end of the expression).

Next, you need to build a regular expression that describes "a possibly empty sequence of word characters and spaces". That would be `(?:\\w|\\s)*`.

Now you are ready to make your expression. You need these parts:

- A capture group that matches a sequence of word characters that begins and ends at a word boundary
- A possibly empty sequence of word characters and spaces that ends at a word boundary
- The value of your captured sequence that ends at a word boundary
- Another possibly empty sequence of word characters and spaces that ends at a word boundary
- The value of your captured sequence that ends at a word boundary

Comment: Thank you for walking me through this. Based on this structure, I think what I need is something like `\\b(\\w+)\\b\\w*\\b\\1\\b\\w*\\b\\1\\b` . But why is the sequence of word characters that ends at a word boundary "possibly empty"? I know that is what `*` is for, so does that describe the spaces between words?

Comment: Never mind, this isn't working, I'm sure simply because I don't fully understand it yet. In your description, do the `\\s++` and `\\w*` serve the same purpose, matching the spaces between words?

Comment: Oh my goodness, I see the light! All I had to do to my original, `\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b` , was to add another space, reference to first group, and word boundary, to yield `\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\s+\\1\\b` .

Now the question is, what if those words are anywhere in the string, and not necessarily consecutive, as in "world hello is hello hello bye" ? (wanting to match hello)

Aha, maybe this has to do with the "possibly empty sequence of word characters" you talked about.

Comment: I think I finally understand, save one thing. `\s*\w*` can be put after the word I want to capture in order to say, optionally match spaces and then another word. How can I repeat that section for as long as there are words that I don't want? (i.e. "hello a a a a a hello hello" would be able to get past all 5 a's)

P.S. I'd vote your answer, but I don't have the reputation yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nathanoday I missed the fact that you could have multiple words in between. Please see the edits. Note the `(?:<expr>)` - that's a non-capturing group of parentheses. Now the asterisk applies to the entire group.

Comment: Going to bed now, but I'll look at it tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: You have officially saved the day. Thank you for helping me work through this problem, but arrive at the final conclusion myself. It's a model of what this site is for. My final regex,

`\\w*\\b(\\w+)\\b(?:\\w|\\s)*\\b\\1\\b(?:\\w|\\s)*\\b\\1\\b`

turned out to be what I need. Thanks again!