# Java Regex to match repeated keywords

Tags: java, regex

I need to filter a document if the caption is the same  surname (i.e.,Smith Vs Smith or John Vs John etc.).
I am converting entire document into a string and validating that string against a regular expression.
Could any one help me to write a regular expression for the above case.

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you elaborate more

Comment: Thanks for the response , I have a string like 'title : Smith Vs Smith'. I need a regular expression to check if the string has same names (i.e.,Smith Vs Smith).

Comment: still not clear better read on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926107/regular-expression-to-match-word-repeated-twice-i-e-hello-hello-hello

Answer (score 2):

[Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Example: `(\w+) Vs \1`

Answer (score 0):

If a had exactly understand your question: you have a string like this "X Vs Y" (Where X and Y are two names) and you want to know if X == Y.

In this case, a simple (\w+) regex can do it :

```
    String input = "Smith Vs Smith";

    // Build the Regex 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    // Store the matches in a list
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        if (!m.group().equals("Vs"))
        {
            str.add(m.group());
        }
    }

    // Test the matches
    if (str.size()>1 && str.get(0).equals(str.get(1)))
        System.out.println(" The Same ");
    else System.out.println(" Not the Same ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w+).*\1
```

This means: a word of 1 or more characters, signed as group 1, followed by  anything, and followed by whatever group 1 is.

More explained: grouping (bracketing part of regex) and referencing to groups defined in the expression ( \1 does that here).

Example:

```
String s = "Stewie is a good guy. Stewie does no bad things";
s.find("(\\w+).*\\1") // will be true, and group 1 is the duplicated word. (note the additional java escape);
```